# If user has mouse over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i track if user has mouseover a element and rightclicks on the right x and y positions?

```
 <div style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px">Hello</div>

 <script>
   if ( MOUSE == divPosition && RIGHTCLICKS on it) {
       //Trigger a javascript function!
   }
 </script>
```

I really hope someone can help me.

It should first find the positions where the element is. After that a multi mouselistiner should track if user rightclicks on the specific position of the element. Without just making "oncontextmenu.." It should be done though jQuery or something, but i am stuck.

I have tried this and works fine, but it's only for "mouseover" element. It should be when user RIGHTCLICKS on the right position!

```
'wierdo' : function(id){
$("#item-" + id).each(function(){
boxX = $(this).offset().left;
boxY = $(this).offset().top;
boxW = $(this).innerWidth();
boxH = $(this).innerHeight();
if ((boxX <= mx) &&
    (boxX + 1000 >= mx) &&
    (boxY <= my) &&
    (boxY + boxH >= my))
{
    // mouse is over it so you can for example trigger a mouseenter event
    alert("Yes....");
    $("#item-" + id).trigger({type: "mousedown",which: 3});

    //$(this).trigger("mouseenter");
}
```

});

Comment: Well, there's no physical way to right click an element without hovering over it, so I don't think you need to check the mouse position. And the event for "right-click" is `contextmenu`. So give the element an `id`, get it with `document.getElementById()`, and look into `addEventListener`

Comment: It should first find the positions where the element is. After that a multi mouselistiner should track if user rightclicks on the specific position of the element. Without just making "oncontextmenu.." It should be done though jQuery or something, but i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are looking for this:

#### Markup:

```
<div class='div'>Hello</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('.div').on('contextmenu', function (e) { //<--contextmenu is right click event
  e.preventDefault();       //<------prevents the right click
  alert('rightClick customized.'); 
});
```

[**Checkout the fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SUd9/)